# Implement suggestions plugin for Eclipse (3.7 and 4.7)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

If you worked, even a little bit, with IntelliJ you know how handy their suggestion system is. An example could be the potential `null` pointer access, where they are able to automatically wrap the statement inside an `if` clause.

I'm working on a closed legacy environment with Eclipse 3.7 and I'm wondering if I can write a plugin, even if not smart like the Jetbrains one, that lets me add some suggestions to the default ones, when pressing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> keyboard shurtcut (the contextual help).

Can you point me in the right direction? What are the important interfaces or abstract classes to look for?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/nav/3

Comment: @nitind I can't find one for 3.7

Comment: Try it with the info you have. APIs don't change that often if they want to be taken seriously.